# Use Cell Attribute in R1C1 Notation

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running a macro where I define lastcolumnbc using the column attribute

```
lastcolumnbc = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
```

Later, I would like to use that attribute in R1C1 to insert a formula into a range:

```
Set rgbe = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lastrow - 1, 2))
rgbe.Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(RC[1]:RC[lastcolumnbc],MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((RC[1]:RC[lastcolumnbc]<>0),0),0))"
Selection.Columns.AutoFit
```

Unfortunately this returns an object-defined error.

Comment: in which line is the error and where and how is lastrow determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing which line throws the error I will assume for now lastrow can be determined in the same way as last column. And that your final error reside with not concatenating the variable outside the string.

Always use option explicit at the top of your code, avoid select and use With statements to be clear on sheet working with. And be careful as xlCellTypeLastCell may actually end up referring to a cell that you didn't expect and may even appear empty.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim lastcolumnbc As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rgbe As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    lastcolumnbc = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

    With ws
         If lastRow <=1 Then Exit Sub 'quit if attempt invalid 
        Set rgbe = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(lastrow - 1, 2)) 'what happens if lastRow is 1 or 0?
        With rgbe
           .FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(RC[1]:RC[" & lastcolumnbc & "],MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((RC[1]:RC[" & lastcolumnbc & "]<>0),0),0))"
          .Columns.AutoFit
       End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: lastrow and lastcolumn are defined the same way: `lastrow = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    lastcolumnbc = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column` Using lastrow to set the range works because I've tested the macro by substituting an integer where I want the lastcolumn to be. e.g., this works: `Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(RC[1]:RC[8],MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((RC[1]:RC[8]<>0),0),0))"`

Comment: Well I made a lucky assumption then :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if it was the `Option Explicit` or the `Dim lastcolumnbc As Long` that did the trick, but that worked, thank you.

Comment: @QHarr You may wanna change that `End` statement to `Exit Sub`. Have a look at the remarks section on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/end-statement

Comment: @KostasK. Thanks.I will amend.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the variable will need to be put in the string for the formulae to work. Like so

```
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(RC[1]:RC[lastcolumnbc],MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((RC[1]:RC["& lastcolumnbc & "]<>0),0),0))"
```

Comment: (Don't forget about `lastcolumnbc`)

Comment: Tried adding the `"& ... &"` in both places, doesn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
rgbe.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(RC[1]:RC[" & lastcolumnbc & "],MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((RC[1]:RC[" & lastcolumnbc & "]<>0),0),0))"
```

Comment: No, unfortunately.

Comment: You didn't answer why didn't this work. Did you get an error? If yes, on which line?

Comment: I think I had an issue with the opening set of definitions in the macro. Per @QHarr above, I added `Option Explicit` and `Dim lastcolumnbc As Long` at the beginning.  That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Well, I addressed the issue you were having trouble with. :)